# jQuery plugin to convert fadeTo, fadeOut,.. functions to CSS3

Tags: jquery, animation, css

Hi is there any jquery extension capable of converting standard animations like fadeOut to CSS3 animations..?
CSS3 is much more quicker but is not widely supported..
I have found only some plugins with those functionality but unfortunately only for $.animate functions..

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use CSS3 transition and, only if browser doesn't support it, use javascript fallbacks. [look at this example](http://www.rcartist.com/2011/01/css3-transitions-with-a-jquery-fallback/).

Comment: It seems to be only proper way, how to do that..thanks..I thought I can avoid rewriting my code..Bad luck:)but thanks

Comment: Yes I think so. Is better to avoid rewriting Css rules with javascript. Also your js will be more clean and performant :)

Answer (score 1):

Take look at [this plugin](http://playground.benbarnett.net/jquery-animate-enhanced/). Sound's like what you're looking for but the number of properties animated with css is rather low.

Comment: yeah, thats what I'found, but ot only supports $.animate:)

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that future releases of jQuery will use CSS3 animations if possible, and fall back to non-CSS3 animations where it is not supported. I cannot confirm this though.

There is some [discussion on the jQuery site](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/4171).